# Ionic/Angular mostrar opciones seleccionadas

Tags: angular, ionic

estoy incursionando en el mundo de ionic y me encontre con algo que no puedo resolver. 
Tengo una lista de botones cada uno conteniendo una imagen, se deberia poder seleccionar/hacer click en varios de los botones y se termina la seleccion haciendo click en un boton al final de la pagina, este boton deberia mostrar un popup con la informacion de las opciones que seleccione.

Ejemplo:

- Una lista con 5 opciones: A B C D E F.
- El usuario selecciona algunas: A **B** C D **E** **F**.
- El usuario hace click en el boton "submit"
- Se muestra un popup con el contenido: **B E F**

Gracias